# Applying ultrapower construction to the field $\mathbb {Q} $ of rationals

Tags: nonstandard-analysis

> Can the ultrapower construction (used for extending the field of real numbers to get the field of hyperreals) be applied to the field $\mathbb{Q} $ of rational numbers?

In my view it should be possible to start with the set $\mathbb{Q} ^{\mathbb {N}} $ of all sequences of rationals and then use equivalence between these sequences based on a free ultrafilter. And my guess is that it should lead to another non-archimedean ordered field $ {} ^*\mathbb{Q} $. More specifically if ${} ^*\mathbb{R} $ is the field of hyperreals then ${} ^*\mathbb {Q} $ should be isomorphic to the set $$\{x\mid x\in{} ^*\mathbb {R}, \text{ standard part of }x\text{ is rational or }x\text{ is an infinite hyperreal number} \} $$

> Do the axioms like Extension Principle, Transfer Principle <strike>and Standard Part Principle</strike> apply in analogous manner to ${} ^*\mathbb{Q} $?

**Update**: Since there are sequences of rationals which converge to an irrational number, most likely the Standard Part Principle will not be valid here. But I don't see if the other two principles have any issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can apply the ultrapower construction to any mathematical object $X$ and get the corresponding object ${}^\ast\!X$ which is then helpful in studying the properties of the original object $X$ itself.

In particular one can apply the ultrapower construction to $\mathbb Q$ producing the ordered field of hyperrational numbers ${}^\ast \mathbb Q$ which can be naturally identified with a subfield of ${}^\ast \mathbb R$.

The transfer principle applies to all ultraproducts; this is essentially a theorem of Jerzy Los from 1955 (i.e., six years before Robinson's first paper on the subject).

Here is an interesting observation developed more fully e.g., in

> Davis, Martin. *Applied nonstandard analysis.* Pure and Applied Mathematics. Wiley-Interscience [John Wiley & Sons], New York-London-Sydney, 1977.

Consider the subring of $F\subseteq{}^\ast \mathbb Q$ consisting of all *finite* hyperrationals, and let $I\subseteq F$ be the subring of all infinitesimals (with the usual definitions of "finite" and "infinitesimal"; I can clarify if necessary).  Then $I$ is a maximal ideal of $F$ and the quotient $F/I$ is naturally isomorphic to the field $\mathbb R$.

In other words, this approach gives an alternative construction of the real field from the rationals that does not require either Dedekind cuts or equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences.

Comment: Your answer has cleared even those doubts which I was not able to formulate clearly. Especially the fact that this construction leads to the reals. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: And I am going through Keisler's book so I am aware of "finite and infinitesimals" as they are used in this theory. The more I read the book I will ask questions on these topics and hopefully be able to understand the whole picture in a much better way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course. In particular you can regard ${}^*\Bbb Q$ as a subfield
of ${}^*\Bbb R$. But it is not the same as the set of hyperreals with rational standard part. Neither inclusion holds; there is an infinite
$x\notin {}^*\Bbb Q$. Then $1/x\notin {}^*\Bbb Q$ but has standard part zero. Also there are infinite elements in ${}^*\Bbb Q$ which have
no standard part.

Comment: But infinite hyperreals also don't have standard part.

Comment: I think I can understand your argument about why ${} ^*\mathbb{Q} $ would not be the set I described in my post. But I think the principle of standard part should apply.

Comment: I have updated the description in my post. Does it make sense now?